# Promise in JavaScript is not running the supertest request

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, es6-promise, supertest

I thought I setup this Promise to attempt to perform a login POST request for a RESTful service using supertest.  However, it is not working for me.

Here is the code:

```
'use strict';

/*
 * loginRequest.js
 *
 * Perform a basic login using supplied values. Only tests for Response Code 200
 */

var base64_encode = require('Base64').btoa
    , request = require('supertest')
    , VerifyUrl = require('./VerifyUrl');

module.exports = loginRequest;

/**
 * Perform a basic login and returns a Promise. It resolves with the response or rejects with the error.
 *
 * @param username {string} The username.
 * @param password {string} The password.
 * @param url {string} The url under test. If not supplied, assumes 'http://localhost:9000/'
 * @returns {Promise} The Promise container of the login request which resolves with the POST response or rejects with the error.
 */
function loginRequest(username, password, url) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        url = VerifyUrl(url);  // Provides a default url if non is supplied, ensures a trailing '/'.
        var authorization = "Basic " + base64_encode(username + ':' + password);  // Yes, I know, not secure.  The app isn't yet production ready.

        console.log("creds = " + username + ':' + password);
        console.log("auth = " + authorization);

        request(url)
            .post('api/users/login')
            .set('authorization', authorization)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200)
            .expect(function() {console.log("Made the expectation.")})
            .end(function (err, res) {
                console.log("Reached the login .end method.");
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

The output from this is:

```
creds = autoTest1465828536379:4ut0T3st
auth  = Basic YXV0b1Rlc3QxNDY1ODI4NTM2Mzc5OjR1dDBUM3N0
```

When I run it through the debugger, with breakpoints on each `request` method, it stops at the .set, but does not run the `.expect` or `.end` methods. What am I missing or not understanding?

Additional info. From the spec script, I am using the above code as follows:

```
var login = require('loginRequest');
var username = 'autoTest' + Date.now();
var password = '4ut0T3st';

login(username, password, 'http://localhost:9000')
    .then(function(loginResponse) {
         // do stuff with the response
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
         // do stuff with the err
    });
```

But it never reaches the `.then` or `.catch` of this call. (The output is as described above.